# Recursive method not stopping even with condition

Tags: c, debugging, recursion, multidimensional-array

recursion doesnt stop even when  its reaches the conditon

```
 bool answer = trouverMot(tab, bankMots, x - 1, y, (longueurMatch + 1), motNumero, positions1) |
                      trouverMot(tab, bankMots, x + 1, y, (longueurMatch + 1), motNumero, positions1) |
                      trouverMot(tab, bankMots, x, y - 1, (longueurMatch + 1), motNumero, positions1) |
                      trouverMot(tab, bankMots, x, y + 1, (longueurMatch + 1), motNumero, positions1);
```

Comment: Note that if you have `char bankMots[13][13]` you can should change the exit condition `if (x < 0 || y < 0 || x >= 12 || y >= 12)` to `if (x < 0 || y < 0 || x >= 13 || y >= 13)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I replace this code:

```
bool answer = trouverMot(tab, bankMots, x - 1, y, (longueurMatch + 1), motNumero, positions1) |
              trouverMot(tab, bankMots, x + 1, y, (longueurMatch + 1), motNumero, positions1) |
              trouverMot(tab, bankMots, x, y - 1, (longueurMatch + 1), motNumero, positions1) |
              trouverMot(tab, bankMots, x, y + 1, (longueurMatch + 1), motNumero, positions1);
return answer;
```

with:

```
bool answer = trouverMot(tab, bankMots, x - 1, y, (longueurMatch + 1), motNumero, positions1) ||
              trouverMot(tab, bankMots, x + 1, y, (longueurMatch + 1), motNumero, positions1) ||
              trouverMot(tab, bankMots, x, y - 1, (longueurMatch + 1), motNumero, positions1) ||
              trouverMot(tab, bankMots, x, y + 1, (longueurMatch + 1), motNumero, positions1);
return answer;
```

I get the expected output `MANDOLINE`.

I think you don't want to recursively search once you've already succeeded (the logical-or operator short-circuits evaluation, the bitwise-or operator does not).